# Django "save() takes no arguments (3 given)"

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a Profile for each user account that gets created. I'm using Django 1.4 and python 2.7.

I've got my `Profile` model class:

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
   ... profile fields ...
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Then I'm using the post save signal to create the `Profile`:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        #Profile(user=instance).save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid="accounts.models")
```

If I use `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` I get the error:

```
save() takes no arguments (3 given)
```

but if I use `Profile(user=instance).save()` I get the error:

```
save() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I basically copied this straight from the django docs.

I'm really not sure what's breaking here, so any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit

Problem was solved in the comments:

> I had def `save():` instead of `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Have you overridden the `save` method in your Profile model? If so, post the code.

Comment: Or you might have a function/field of the Profile class named 'save'?

Comment: yeah, that was it.  I had def save(): instead of def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`save()` takes `self` as default argument. So if not passed explicitly, Django will automatically pass `self` default argument.

So you need to pass `self` explicitly to `save()`, i.e `def save(self)` and then call `save()` anywhere, and you won't get the error again.

Comment: This problem was already solved in the comments 2(!) years ago, and while your answer partially covers what was wrong with the OP's code, isn't it just easier to upvote his comment that _completely solved his problem_?

Comment: @Neftas : Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to do so.Hence i was trying to contribute in my own way.But people like you seem to have developed a sense of competition within yourself regarding this upvote/downvote thing.Raise yourself from all of this and try n focus on things you need to.

Comment: [Voting is one of the cornerstones of the SE model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Upvotes indicate that certain content is useful for future readers, downvotes indicate that the community doesn't think it's useful. Voting has nothing to do with _competition_: it is simply a filter mechanism.

Comment: But since i am new to Stack Overflow, i still don't have enough reputation to upvote someone's comment.Hence i tried to explain things myself.Got it?

Comment: Well, actually you are right in one thing: unanswered questions with the solution in the comments should preferably get a real accepted answer. But this particular question should probably be closed, because it all comes down to simply forgetting to put `self` in a class method.

Comment: @ Neftas : I agree with you on this.There has to be a way to either mark any comment as accepted or close these unanswered questions after a specific duration.

Comment: That was not exactly what I meant. I meant to say that your intent of answering unanswered questions that were solved in the comments is good, as it is preferred to have all valid questions answered for future readers (as discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)). But questions like these that come down to typos and such should be closed, not because they haven't got an answer for a while, but because they are not good questions.